# Java polymorphism performance

Tags: java, performance, polymorphism, profiler

I am profiling some java code that is calling an abstract method a great number of times. The profiler (visual vm) shows time is spent in the specialized versions of derived classes, which is normal, but there is also a big amount of time spent in the abstract method of my interface, which contains nothing. I suspect it comes from runtime type checking.

In C++, I usually use templates instead of inheritance in this critical cases to use compile time polymorphism which is faster.

What would the equivalent be in Java?

Is there a way to speed up this part of my code?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Add a code snippet showing us what you're trying to do. And what is "a big amount of time" ?

Comment: No time can possibly be spent in the abstract method. You must be misinterpreting something, or the profiling tool is giving you wrong data.

Comment: Ok I mean the time is not spent "in" the abstract method, but the VM has to check the type somehow in run time to call the right overloaded method. You can avoid this in C++ using static polymorphism and inline functions.

Comment: JVM inlines functions automatically when there's opportunity. It also employs monomorphic/polymorphic inline caching. Are you just guessing on the cost, or do you have some specific data to back up your intuition?

Comment: I don't think "the VM" has to check the types to call the right overloaded method -- I think the compiler does that.  Java is a strongly typed language (still, mostly, and at least for the time being); when a statement making a call is compiled, the compiler looks at the types and determines which method matches those types, then fashions a call that uses the correct place out of the jump table to match them.  [BTW, Without numbers, or a user experience, or something specific that needs speeding up, the chances of speeding up the right things are small.]